# ifstream doesn't read the double to the end c++

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I am trying to do external sorting by reading a big file and writing them into small pieces first. But when I get double values with ifstream from the file although the numbers are 12 digits, it only gets first 6 digit.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


using namespace std;


void createRun(double *arr, int size, int orderoffile){
  make_heap(arr, arr+size);
  for(int i=0; i<size ;i++){
    pop_heap(arr, arr+size-i);
  }
  string filename = "sortedTemp" ;
  filename += to_string(orderoffile) + ".txt";

  ofstream ofs(filename.c_str());

  for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++){
    ofs<<arr[i]<<endl;
  }
  ofs<<arr[size-1];
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

ifstream ifs(argv[1]);

int num;
ifs>>num;

int files=num/1024;
double arr[1024];


for(int i=0; i<files ; i++ ){
  for(int j=0 ; j<1024;j++){

    ifs>>arr[j];

  }
  createRun(arr, 1024 ,i);
}

int remaining;
if(num%1024!=0){
  remaining =num%1024;
  files++;

  for(int i=0 ; i< remaining; i++){
    ifs>>arr[i];
  }
  createRun(arr, remaining ,files-1);

}
ifs.close();

  return 0;


}
```

The file I am trying to read is contains 2048 doubles, I copied the first 32.The first integer just gives the number of doubles in file.

>

```
 2048
185261.886524
237358.956723
139921.832662
128702.977104
93468.067919
415572.438294
394341.383634
317808.343493
63075.462939
907012.789025
393656.286891
418873.927354
892347.117718
764276.357958
300568.750436
717272.259456
354591.446610
431749.187142
63565.857898
288241.215494
526117.693273
680793.623315
68218.415160
391965.952529
66870.811087
3982.888630
469794.327128
492466.036574
865900.028660
717094.169557
32770.089775
```

it just writes the file like this.

```
836.661
3366.63
3982.89
5394.17
6764.96
9018.77
9034.42
9058.47
10259.5
11236.4
12419.8
13368.7
13659.5
13876
15553.6
15657.5
16682.7
17647.7
19490.9
19519
19632.4
19936.8
22118
23157.6
23718.4
23781.5
24640.4
24889.4
25054.2
25151.9
25647.5
26293.4
```

Comment: Wich anomalies did you obeserve when debugging in particular?

Comment: First I thought that the precision is just about the array but I try to get one value from file and print it, It gave me the same result.

Comment: Are You sure You are reading data? Try `static double arr[1024];` or fill this array with zeros manually.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The number I showed here is just the first 32 sorted number from 2048 doubles.

Comment: The problem was about the output. I used fprintf() and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Binary floating points don't know how many significant digits there may be (this is to some extend different to decimal floating points which are not normalized and indicate a number of significant digits). Floating point numbers are formatted based on the flag stored in the `precision()` field of a stream. If you want to retain more digits you could consider using `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10` as a potential setup. Note that depending on the values and other formatting flags (notably whether `std::ios_base::fixed` is set) you may defeat the formatting algorithm and get values which are not properly rounded but more closely represent that actually stored binary value than the approximated decimal value.

Answer (score 1):

To preserve the formatting of your numbers, you should read them as strings rather than as doubles. Then you have 3 options for the actual sorting:

1. Compare the strings directly. This can get tricky as you need to track the decimal point and allow for a possible negative sign at the front - there will be lots of edge cases.
2. Convert the string to a double each time you need to compare.
3. Instead of keeping an array of double or string, create a structure that contains both and populate the array with that. Use the double for comparison, and the string for output.